# Can't resolve Mac's machine name on VPN

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vpn

My mac'c machine name is something like this: **hostname.company.com** but whenever I connect to VPN, it becomes something like **vpn-xxxx.company.com** where xxxx are some random numbers. Because of this, some of my scripts which are dependent on host name gets blocked.

We use the standard mac's vpn setup which comes with OS X Lion (under network preferences).

How can I resolve to the correct mac's name even if I am on vpn  ?  That is even if I am connected to VPN, my machine name should resolve to **hostname.company.com** and **NOT** to **vpn-xxxx.company.com**.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually setting the hostname on your workstation? Is the computer bound to an LDAP / Active Directory?

In a terminal run

```
sudo scutil --set HostName <yourhostname>
```

(Hostnames can be dynamically assigned via DHCP, which is likely what is happening, depending on how the VPN and internal network are configured, so setting the hostname by hand may not help.)